# Python: if statements under except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have an empty list n. n should have 10 float-point values taken from the user. If the user enters e, the code should break out of the loop. If the user enters any other text (not a number), it should display "Not a number" and continue taking values from the user. I tried the following code. When I enter e as an input, the code doesn't break out of the for loop and always go the else block and displays "Not a number". How do I rectify this?

```
n = []
for i in range(10):
    try:
        inp_val = float(input('Enter value (e to exit)'))
        n.append(inp_val)

    except ValueError:
        if inp_val == 'e'
            break
        else:
            print("not a number")
            continue
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your if and if the user enters e straight away you  will have an undefined error. You also won't get 10 numbers if there are errors

Comment: there are few issues, but I think the big one that you're missing is that if float(input('Enter value (e to exit)'))  raises an error than inp_val will never be assigned.  I see some answers are starting to form below, so I won't bother adding one.

Comment: @user3535492, why are you even giving an option to quit when you are trying to get a list with 10 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
inp_val = float(input('Enter value (e to exit)'))
```

This is executed like this:

```
temp_val = input('Enter value (e to exit)')
temp_val = float(temp_val)
inp_val = temp_val
```

So at the time the `ValueError` is raised because you are trying to convert the `'e'`, `inp_val` has not been assigned yet. So when you check the value of `inp_val` in your `except` block, you are not comparing the entered value.

In order to do that, you need to actually store the string input separately:

```
try:
    text_input = input('Enter value (e to exit)')
    inp_val = float(text_input)
    n.append(inp_val)
except ValueError:
    if text_input == 'e':
        break
    else:
        print("not a number")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

`inp_val` is set with a `float` value, so it can never be `e`. One way around this is to assign `inp_val` to the inputted value and convert it to float when appending the list:

```
n = []
for i in range(10):
    try:
        inp_val = input('Enter value (e to exit)')
        n.append(float(inp_val))

    except ValueError:
        if inp_val == 'e'
            break
        else:
            print("not a number")
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you get 10 numbers, use a [while loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) which keeps looping until you get ten numbers in the list  and forget getting the user to quit, it makes no sense quitting until then  if *I have an empty list n. n should have 10 float-point values taken from the user.*:

```
n = []
while len(n) < 10:
    try:
        inp_val = float(input('Enter value'))
        n.append(inp_val)
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number")
```

When `len(n) < 10` evaluate to False you will have ten floats stored in your list, you cannot do the same using range as when an iteration is over there is no going back.

To correct your own code you just need a couple of changes, only cast after you check if the input is equal to `e`, if it is break or else try to append a float to the list, the else/continue are both also  redundant in your own code, you could not break and get to the print and your loop is going to continue regardless when you reach the last line in your code:

```
n = []
for i in range(10):
    try:
        inp_val = (input('Enter value (e to exit)'))
        if inp_val == "e":
            break
        n.append(float(inp_val))
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number")
```

But again if you want to make sure you get 10 numbers then this or any logic using just range is not going to work, you need the while.

Answer (score 0):

`inp_val = float(input('Enter value (e to exit)'))`

If a `ValueError` exception is raised in this line, `inp_val` won't be assigned, so `if inp_val == 'e'` will evaluate to False.

Fix it by splitting this line to 2:

```
inp_val = input('Enter value (e to exit)')
try:
    flt_inp_val = float(inp_val)
except ValueError:
    if inp_val == 'e'
         break
    else:
        print("not a number")
        continue
```